# Parent scrollview interferes with child scrollview

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiscrollview

I have a scrollview(B) within a scrollview(A) where both of them scrolls horizontally. When scrolling the child scrollview(B) beyond its content size it starts scrolling the parent scrollview(A).

I am trying to block this behaviour and only scroll the child(B) when touch is detected within child scrollviews bounds and never scroll parent scrollview(A) unless the touch is detected out of the child scrollviews bounds.

Many thanks for the support!!

Comment: Ensure the child view is smaller than its parent view